# How to trigger onclick event on an anchor tag after page load in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, onload-event

I was working with an html document in that i've a navigation menu. i want to trigger a click event on the home navigation in onload() iw wrote something but it wont work and i couldn't find a solution on this some one please help me to fix this

**code**

```
<html>
<head>
<nav id="navigation" class="navigation" role="navigation" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">

        <ul id="navigation-primary" class="navigation-primary"><li id="menu-item-29" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-6 current_page_item menu-item-29"><a href="http://example.com/">Home</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28"><a href="http://example.com/events/">Gigs</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-31" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-31"><a href="http://example.com/videos/">Videos</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-79" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-79"><a href="http://example.com/gallery/">Gallery</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-149" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-149"><a href="http://example.com/about-us/">Bio</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-477" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-477"><a href="http://example.com/media-kit/">Media Kit</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-514" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-514"><a href="http://example.com/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
    </nav>
    <head>
    <body>
    fsfsfsfdfs
    sfdgdfg
    sgvsdfg
    dfbd
    b
    xcfb
    dcf
    bcb
    vb
    cvb
    cvbc
    bvc
    bc
    bnc
    bcb
    cb
    cb
    c
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function(){
          $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#menu-item-29").children.trigger('click');
});
        };

    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: `.children.trigger` looks very invalid - what does the console say?

Comment: I see two <head> tags, and no </head> closing tags.

Comment: `children()` not `children` as it is a function + `trigger()` will fire handlers you attached, not default browsers behaviours

Comment: And btw, why nesting document ready handler inside window onload handler, looks like you copy/paste code without trying to understand it

Comment: sorry i forgot to import jQuery 1.8.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to redirect user simulating anchor click, then call native DOM click method:

```
$("#menu-item-29").children('a').get(0).click();
```

Comment: It works for me! http://jsfiddle.net/yfS6x/  Now you should provide relevant code in question, currently, your HTML markup is not valid and doesn't make much sense... Did you try to understand what you have copied/pasted???

Comment: This is the correct answer. You may have something else wrong with your code.

Comment: its working the thing is, i forgot to include jQuery

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to include JQuery source when you use `$(document).ready`

And `children()` is a function. Look at the documentation : http://api.jquery.com/children/