# jquery trigger click if url contains parameter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

hi i'm trying to automatically click the 9th child of li tag when the URL contains "ddg" parameter. I've tried this one but using jQuery i can't get it working. the code is within the document.ready function. thanks!

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("ddg") > -1) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#nav-categories li:nth-child(9)").trigger("click");
    },1000);
}
```

Comment: Checking the simple stuff first... have you confirmed that your jQuery link is pointing to the correct spot?  If you "view source", and click on the jQuery link, does it load the jQuery text?

Comment: yes. before i put the settimeout function, i put alert first to check if the code works and resulted ok.

Comment: Alert doesn't require jQuery, it is pure javascript.  What happens if you put `$('#nav').hide();`?  Does the navigation disappear?  That would be a better test to confirm your jQuery is loaded.

Comment: yes it did disappear.

Comment: what is clicking on the `li` supposed to do? Has a click handler been assigned to it before you trigger click...is it a jQuery click handler or native one?

Comment: @charlietfl the li will show a popup and subcategories. i'm just using the trigger function.

Comment: I'm not sure what your trigger should look like... please see my fiddle for an example of how it may work.  If you click on the first `li`, it will turn yellow.   Or if you just wait for 1 second, it will turn yellow.  See https://jsfiddle.net/sablefoste/p4wwe38x/1/

Comment: @Sablefoste thanks for that. but i'm trying to click the li thru jquery after the page loads. it's like automatic click.

Comment: Exactly (my fiddle represents a click turning the first `li` yellow).  Regardless, have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867433/how-to-trigger-onclick-event-on-an-anchor-tag-after-page-load-in-javascript?  `$("#nav-categories li:nth-child(9)").get(0).click();` is what you are looking for inside the `setTimeout`.

Comment: okay i'll check it. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Double check that your selector is correct.  I swapped out "ddg" with "_display" so that it would work in jsfiddle.  Hope this helps!

Using jQuery 1.7.2:

https://jsfiddle.net/shawn1/14r2g3d3/

html

```
<ol id="nav-categories">
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li id="test"></li>
<li></li>
</ol>
```

JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  //setup click event
  $( "#test" ).on( "click", function() {
    $( this ).html("clicked");
  });

  //click item if url contains _display
  if(window.location.href.indexOf("_display") !== -1) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#nav-categories li:nth-child(9)").trigger("click");
    },1000);
  }

});
```